# why I can not use create method out side a function in AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

**My app is crashing when I launch when I write code like this**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song);
    public void playMusic(View view){
        mplayer.start();
    }
    public void pauseMusic(View view){
        mplayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

**but when I write above code like this then it's working perfectly fine**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mplayer;
    public void playMusic(View view){
        mplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song);
        mplayer.start();
    }
    public void pauseMusic(View view){
        mplayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

please anybody tell me what is wrong with first code

Thanks

Comment: upload crash report also

Comment: The first parameter in `create()` is a `Context`. An `Activity` has not yet been set up to act as a `Context` until `onCreate()` runs.

Comment: Thank you So much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the player must be initialized at the moment when the context is not empty. That is, in the upper code, context == null in player. Therefore, the application crashes.